# What causes memory leak in my code using kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am bothering title's trouble. I showed in below my code shorten according to its code structure. The code assumes to be saved as filename "revival_memory_leak.py". The memory leak occurred at command `return Rectangle(size=...)` and so on, which found by tracemalloc module. Is there any tip that I can release the memory of instance generated Rectangle class?

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color, Line, Rectangle
import tracemalloc
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.config import Config

width = 400
height = 300
Config.set('graphics', 'width', str(width))
Config.set('graphics', 'height', str(height))


class MyClass(Widget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.cnt_of_loop = 0
        self.gid = "1111"  # Group ID
        self.step_width = 10
        self.pos_x = 0

    def start(self):
        # start loopmethod()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.loop, 0.01)

    def get_rectangle(self):
        self.pos_x += self.step_width
        if self.pos_x >= width:
            self.pos_x = self.step_width
        # This method returns customized every time kivy.graphics.Rectangle class instance
        # The below code seems to cause one of memory leak
        return Rectangle(size=(10, 30), pos=(self.pos_x, height / 2), group=self.gid)  # generate a Rectangle instance with gid "1111"

    def update_canvas(self):
        self.canvas.remove_group(self.gid)  # clear all canvas items with gid:"1111"
        self.canvas.add(Color(1, 0, 1, self.gid))
        self.canvas.add(self.get_rectangle())  # add new canvas one more items

    def loop(self, dt):
        """ This method called repeatedly and infinity """

        self.update_canvas()
        """ Show difference between used memory and it at step 10"""
        if self.cnt_of_loop == 10:
            self.snapshot1 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
        if self.cnt_of_loop > 200:
            snapshot2 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
            top_stats = snapshot2.compare_to(self.snapshot1, 'lineno')

            print("[ Top 10 differences]")
            for stat in top_stats[:10]:
                print(stat)
        self.cnt_of_loop += 1


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # return MyClass()
        a = MyClass()
        a.start()
        return a


if __name__ == '__main__':
    tracemalloc.start()
    MyApp().run()
```

- Result:

  - Please attention rows written as "revival_memory_leak.py". The command written at the attention rows seemed memory size increased. The below two "Top 10 differences" shows result of early stage and later stage. For example, "revival_memory_leak.py:37" ,which indicates the line 37 of file revival_memory_leak.py, memory size was increased to 276KiB from 179KiB. Why not release memory? I thought that the memory releases of drawing object(e.g. Rectangle) when called remove_group method.
- "early stage" of memory consumption

```
[ Top 10 differences]
revival_memory_leak.py:37: size=179 KiB (+177 KiB), count=2421 (+2396), average=76 B
python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py:1343: size=177 KiB (+176 KiB), count=1205 (+1190), average=150 B
revival_memory_leak.py:33: size=140 KiB (+136 KiB), count=4430 (+4345), average=32 B
python3.6/tracemalloc.py:113: size=90.1 KiB (+90.1 KiB), count=1049 (+1049), average=88 B
python3.6/site-packages/kivy/weakmethod.py:56: size=75.8 KiB (+75.0 KiB), count=1078 (+1066), average=72 B
revival_memory_leak.py:53: size=57.8 KiB (+57.8 KiB), count=919 (+919), average=64 B
python3.6/tracemalloc.py:117: size=57.0 KiB (+57.0 KiB), count=912 (+912), average=64 B
revival_memory_leak.py:51: size=55.8 KiB (+55.8 KiB), count=893 (+893), average=64 B
python3.6/site-packages/kivy/cache.py:211: size=18.8 KiB (+18.4 KiB), count=300 (+295), average=64 B
python3.6/site-packages/kivy/clock.py:581: size=14.0 KiB (+11.6 KiB), count=198 (+185), average=72 B
```

- "later stage" of memory consumption

```
[ Top 10 differences ]
python3.6/site-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py:1343: size=283 KiB (+283 KiB), count=1854 (+1839), average=156 B
revival_memory_leak.py:37: size=276 KiB (+274 KiB), count=3732 (+3707), average=76 B
revival_memory_leak.py:33: size=187 KiB (+182 KiB), count=6432 (+6347), average=30 B
python3.6/site-packages/kivy/weakmethod.py:56: size=114 KiB (+113 KiB), count=1623 (+1611), average=72 B
revival_memory_leak.py:53: size=93.5 KiB (+93.5 KiB), count=1490 (+1490), average=64 B
python3.6/tracemalloc.py:117: size=92.6 KiB (+92.6 KiB), count=1482 (+1482), average=64 B
python3.6/tracemalloc.py:113: size=90.4 KiB (+90.4 KiB), count=1052 (+1052), average=88 B
revival_memory_leak.py:51: size=90.0 KiB (+90.0 KiB), count=1440 (+1440), average=64 B
python3.6/site-packages/kivy/cache.py:211: size=34.9 KiB (+34.6 KiB), count=559 (+554), average=64 B
python3.6/tracemalloc.py:387: size=16.2 KiB (+16.2 KiB), count=226 (+226), average=73 B
```

Comment: Your code gives error: `NameError: name 'App' is not defined`

Comment: Your code has a number of problems. It needs an external library (tracemalloc) and I don't thing that anybody is going to install it just to check it. Also, the `__init__` method has nothing in it. And even if all these are fixed, it opens an empty window doing no updates at all. Do you expect us to do your example for you?

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. The code were repaired. The code can be ran. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to have solved my problem to use InstructionGroup class instead of adding graphic items into canvas directly. Thank you for your cooperations.